# Failed to import Bech32 SegWit addresses using importmulti Bitcoin-Core 0.16.0rc3

Tags: bitcoin-core, importaddress, bech32-address

I was trying to import Bech32 addresses using `importmulti` on Bitcoin Core 0.16.0rc3.

```
       [
    {
        "scriptPubKey" : { "address": "tb1qkzq7kgx7rk45na3d3vt6vrqftfczq6ryn9zq0d" },
        "timestamp" : "now",
        "watchonly" : "true"
    }
  ] ,  { "rescan": false }
```

**Response:**

Please enter the wallet passphrase with walletpassphrase first.

---

Why that error? and shouldn't I add witness scrpit instead of scriptPubKey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  should type your wallet passphrase before importing any addresses or private keys.

'walletpassphrase yourpassword 60' would unlock your wallet for 60 seconds. You should import the addresses in that 60 seconds. (Type the walletpassphrase command again if you couldn't import your addresses in that 60 seconds)

Comment: But I'm importing watchonly addresses, I don't think that's correct! Since I don't have a passphrase, my wallet isn't encrypted and i tried the same command on litecoin and bitcoin cash and it did work.

Comment: I don't know why was that, I tried to remove wallet.dat and tried again and it did work.

Comment: This is unrelated.

Comment: Actually i had two problems and that was the first problem.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the Bitcoin Core 0.16 release notes, `importmulti` does not support SegWit addresses yet. This will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: it could be weird, But I've imported an address using importmulti and I've got success equals to true, then I've sent some TestNet bitcoins and it did work!!

Comment: [
  {
    "involvesWatchonly": true,
    "account": "",
    "address": "tb1qh2sdesazn9ac34xk3qt4d2jn0vhd993hjrkk9h",
    "category": "receive",
    "amount": 0.10000000,
    "label": "",
    "vout": 0,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "trusted": false,
    "txid": "48089a814ac571944feb7162cc0145eea4e72742aa51f6f23d470debd838eeb3",
    "walletconflicts": [
    ],
    "time": 1519713147,
    "timereceived": 1519713147,
    "bip125-replaceable": "yes"
  }
]

Comment: I've made a separate question on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12554